# Using Dependency Injection in Spring to replace Factory pattern

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I am currently working on an application in which the an instance of the domain object D is injected in to the application. The domain object can contain many classes together in different combinations and permutations as defined by its bean and hence leading to many different final objects D, which I refer to as different versions of D. For a given version of D, I have to fill up the primitive values in it and then save it to the database. Saving it to the database is pretty simple using JPA and Hibernate. The problem is filling up the values in D. The values are fetched over the network using SNMP and then filled up. For each version of D, there is different a strategy to follow, since each version of D may have a different MIB. I are currently following the factory pattern. The factory takes a version of D and returns a valueRetriever for specific to that version of D, which is then used to fetch the values and fill D.

The other obvious way is to inject a configuration retriever in with D and then use it to retrieve the configuration. But I also need to use the retriever during runtime to re-fetch the configurations, so that makes it necessary to store the retriever too in the database, hence creating a new table for each retriever, which seems to an overhead currently.

My question is: Can there be a better way to retrieve the configurations i.e. have a valueRetriever given the above scenario using dependency injection.

**Edit**: Can AOP be of any use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some of the objects you needing to create have a complex creation logic. You may wont to look at the Spring FactoryBean interface, since a FactoryBean can get all the complex details over the network while allowing you to create an instance and then inject it into other beans.

Comment: This might be ok during the instantiation from the defining bean, but what will happen after persisting it in the database? After storing , inorder to retrieve values during runtime i.e. after loading D from the database, will this BeanFactory based Factory, still be able to supply the retriever? If this is not true, then I will have to somehow find a way to persist the factory or retriever with D. It will then be pretty similar to injecting a retriever with D itself as what retriever to use will be known but persisting this retriever in the DB is necessary then.

Answer (score 0):

The basis for Spring's DI *is* the Bean Factory/Application Context, so it's entirely possible to replace what you're doing.

The difference will be that you'll have to be able to put all your permutations into the Spring configuration and give control over to the application context.  If you can't do that, perhaps the solution you've got is preferred.

UPDATE: I would start to fear that your Spring solution is adding in too many unfamiliar technologies into what might be an overly complicated situation.

Take a breath and think "simple".

I wouldn't worry about the database for now.  The Spring application context will be the database if you can get all the combinations you need into the bean factory.  I'm assuming these configurations are read-only and not altered once you declare them.  If that's not the case all bets are off.

Comment: Yes, a BeanFactory might be pretty helpful as it will wire the retriever without any extra code, if the object was always to be created from the application context. But will that work too when I load the objects from the database? Will this BeanFactory provide the object with the retriever? The spring application context will not come into play in this scenario, so I will have to keep some entity stored in the DB with the domain object itself.

Comment: How is loading them from the database - a persistent store - any different from initializing them from the Spring configuration?  You keep insisting that it's necessary, but I still don't see a reason why.  Please explain with something besides "I said so" or "This is how I'm doing it".  I'd love to read a cogent explanation.

Comment: I was actually asking a clarification on the BeanFactory. What I meant was, when I use entityManager.load(id), how is the BeanFactory invoked, other than using a post-load interceptor. The BeanFactory was defined in the bean which defined this object during the first instantiation. How does it come to play in this scenario? I haven't used BeanFactory, so I might be missing out on a lot of naive points. Please bear with me.